# how to get the user friends list using facebook (read_friendlists) drupal 7

Tags: drupal, facebook-graph-api, drupal-7

Hello,

I am doing a website using drupal 7 and I do the registration by FB manually I don't wanna use any available module in drupal.

now I want to get the fb friend list of the user who connect to my site and get whose of his friends also connected to my site too.

any suggestions ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Equivalent to old GetAppUsers call to see a user's friends who use my app?](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/7956639/equivalent-to-old-getappusers-call-to-see-a-users-friends-who-use-my-app)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$friends_list = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/me/friends?access_token=' . $atoken );
$friends_list_array  = json_decode($friends_list,true);
$arr= $friends_list_array['data'];
$friend_ids_arr = array();
foreach($arr as $friend) {
    $friend_ids_arr[] = $friend['id'];
}
$friend_ids = implode("," , $friend_ids_arr);
echo $friend_ids; // output: id1,id2,id3...etc
```

Answer (score 1):

> any suggestions ?

How about: Read documentation …?

The user’s friendlist can be accessed via the Graph API under [/me/friends](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?method=GET&path=me/friends)